# why latest version of jquery make this code not working

Tags: jquery

I use jquery to make a `side menu` in `mobile view` I use this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/codefuze/HYjEB/1/) and it's working but when I change it to `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` the code is not working. can someone have an idea why this is happen.

this is the [working one](http://jsfiddle.net/codefuze/HYjEB/1/)

and this is the [latest and not working](http://jsfiddle.net/7qoagpdo/)

```
$('#button').toggle( 
    function() {
        $('#right').animate({ left: 100 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#button').html('Close');
        });
    }, 
    function() {
        $('#right').animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#button').html('Menu');
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you read [the upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event is deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9.

> ***Note:*** This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.

Comment: thank's so this is the explanation I want. few minutes to accept your answer

Comment: @IreneoCrodua Sure. Always be sure to read the guides. `:)` It will be handy all the time! `:)`